# Automating color fill for multiple worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

Kind of a noob to Excel and I just discovered conditional formatting. 
I'm doing this repetitive process where I color fill a set of cells to be the same color but I have to do them individually. 
I'd like to set up a conditional format along the lines of

If 'B3' is Green, then all cells containing 'word' are also Green

Alternatively, I could probably list all of the cells that need to change as they are the same cells that need changing day to day. Something like

If 'B3' is green, then 'D3, F3, H3, J3' are also green.

Is it possible to do this in excel, if so then how? 
Thanks for any help!

---

My original question was a bit flawed. After working with it some more today, I figured it out.

My goal was to have a list of cells (D3, F3, H3, J3, L3, N3) automatically change to a color corresponding to a given day of the week. Yellow = Sat , Green = Sun, Red = Tue, Blue = Wed/Thur

Before, I would right click each cell and choose yellow for each one, and the same with green the next day, etc. I had to do this for the above range of cells on each of 3 worksheets. Tedious. The idea was to change a single value and have all of the colors change across the sheets.

Comment: What causes B3 to be green? Is it arbitrarily set green or is there some rule you haven't disclosed?

Comment: The coloring on b3 is (currently) input manually. Whether it is green or another color is dependent on the day of the week. Sat (Yellow) Sun (Green) Tue (Red) Wed/Thur (Blue)

Comment: So there is a cell with a date (possibly B3) and if its weekday is Sunday then B3 is green?

Comment: That's right, but I do that process manually. So the date tomorrow is Sunday 2/16/20 & I enter that into cell A1. When I go to edit the file, I know Sun = Green so I color cells B3, D3, F3, etc. Green. I would like it to have it be that if the date in A1 is a Sunday, cells B3, D3, F3 etc auto color to Green, and so on with other days of the week.

Answer (score 1):

The basis of my solution involves the WEEKDAY function and the day's date. I used C1 as the cell for the date. 2/16/20 This is the value that will be changed to result in the desired effect.

I chose a cell I didn't care about/was away from the chart. In this case, C26.

"   =WEEKDAY(C1)    " outputs a digit based on the date referenced in C1, Sunday being 1.

Next, I selected one of the cells I wanted to change the color for (D3).

> Conditional Formatting >New Rule >Enter a custom formula

In the formula box, I entered "      =C26=1      "  And selected Green as the color fill in the format section.

This is the rule used to highlight a cell Green for Sundays. I applied this same rule to the other cells and worksheets. Then, I altered this rule for the other days/colors "=C26=3"/Red for Tue, etc. rinse and repeat.

This system takes the weekday from the date and correctly applies the needed color fills. Changing the value in C1 by 1 or 2 digits will now change the color schemes for all necessary cells on all 3 sheets.